# "Unable to display the webpart..." error at the first time and after refreshing the page it goes off

Tags: web-part, error

Following error encounters at the first time and after refreshing the page it goes off.

*"Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists, contact your Web server administrator.
Correlation ID:1e89ad26-66f7-415a-be16-8e05e9580017".*

It strangely comes only for the first time of everyday.

When I checked the log based on the correlation Id in error message, I could only see the following message:

> Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (GET:http://siteURL/Lists/List/NewItem.aspx?Source=http%3A%2siteURLe%2FLists%2FList%2FAllItems%2Easpx&RootFolder=%2Fadmin%2FGovernance%2FLists%2FShareSitesList&ContentTypeId=0x0100352144B20CC27B4283CBEEAA8F0DE33901009CAD844D4E1B3E4E9327D8A04A9FF4BD)). Execution Time=27284.2146138685

This still leaves no clue to me for further resolution. Any sort of help is highly appreciated.

**Stepwise description and scenario of the error:**

1. I have created a custom new form called newItem.aspx for my SharePoint list. 2. I applied my own css for custom styling mainly related to font color, bg color and other sort of appearances.
2. **I have not added any additional webpart into this form.**
3. I attached custom .js file for validation of the form.
4. The form works absolutely fine, however, it is just at the first time when I open it, it gives the error.
   *Note:* I am using SP2010 with cumulative update 14.0.7171.5000.

Comment: Which version (CU) of SharePoint are u running? Which web part is throwing this error, e.g. CQWP?

Comment: I am running SP2010 and using the custom newitem.aspx for the SharePoint list. I have made some customization for hiding and showing some fields and applying the desired business logic.

Comment: And which update of SP2010 (e.g. April 2017 Cumulative Update (build 14.0.7180.5001))? Did this error started to appear after some particular change? Can you confirm it appears when opening the `newitem.aspx` for the first time of the day? If so, which web parts, or what content does that page have? There are a lot of open questions, which I hope you could detail and edit to the original question as well.

Comment: Thanks for showing your interest in answering my query and sorry for not being very clear with my message. The CU is 14.0.7171.5000. 
Stepwise description and scenario of the error: 

1. I have created a custom new form calles newItems.aspx for my SharePoint list.
2. I applied my own css to for custom styling related to font color, bg color and other sort of apperances.
3.*I have not added any additonal webpart into this form.*
4.I attached custom .js file for validation of the form.
5.The form works fine, however it is just that at the first time when I open it gives the error.

Comment: Thanks, now the question looks like an exemplary one. Previously there has been similar issues as bugs which have been fixed through updates, but I'm not aware of such fixes between your build and the most recent build. CSS changes shouldn't cause issues, .JS could. If the page doesn't log any JS errors to the console when approaching the page, I'd give a shot by creating a copy of your current `newItem.aspx` approach for creating a new item, but not including the .JS validation, and see if issues occur with that one too.

Comment: can you see if you get any error in browser console (F12-->console) when page first loads

Comment: There is no error on the browser console. Once I refresh the page the page loads well without any error. However, it gives this error for the first time to every user who tries to access it(If the user tries to access it on the next day, the same error appears but vanishes again on refreshing it).

Comment: @moe,Thanks for your suggestion! I tried removing the .js files, however, the issue is still there. Also, I would like to bring to your notice that the same issue is not there in development environment, I have copied the portion of elements from NewItem.aspx of dev to the staging environment where I am getting this issue, I feel there is something wrong with the elements in .aspx page.

Comment: @Rajiv that seems likely. I've seen a similar issue where the XML-elements had some wrong syntax, and if I remember correctly, one of the properties existed twice in the same element or such. I'm afraid I can't find a link to that case, but since the functions (by JS) should be alright, it seems like a time for a code-review on your .aspx page.